# Rails link_to with onclick to google analytics event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I am trying to do event tracking with Google Analytics and link_to in rails.  The resulting link is not including the onclick like it does with buttons and forms.  How do I achieve the below?

```
= link_to 'TRIGGER EVENT', new_event_path, {:onClick=> "ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Triggered Event', , '',);"}
```

Comment: this code works as expected `= link_to 'TRIGGER EVENT', '#', {:onClick=> "alert('1');"}`. I think you should check  the `ga();` function.

Comment: You're right, it works as expected.  Turned out that the code I included was not actually being called in the application like I was expecting - a parent conditional was preventing it from being called.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the javascript in the onclick event. You also have some unnecessary ruby in there. Try this cleaner syntax:

```
link_to 'TRIGGER EVENT', new_event_path, onclick: "ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'Triggered Event', '');"
```

Comment: Good call on the unnecessary ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You should run away from `onclick` as much as you can.

Check this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) on Unobtrusive Javascript and move your code the javascript files in assets.

You can change your code with something similar like this:

```
$(#your-link-id)..click(function(){
 ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'Triggered Event');
});
```